# One of the roots of the quadratic equation is positive and the other is negative

Tags: quadratics, mathematica, quadratic-variation

One of the roots of the quadratic 
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$  is positive and the other is negative.
Tell me the sign of a,b,c so that this happens.

Comment: The two solutions are $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  Can you use this to produce two inequalities that help you?

Comment: @RubenduBurck i did the same but i am not able to solve inequality. .

Comment: You can use Descartes's sign rule. In the coefficients $a,b,c$ , there must be exactly one sign change. Moreover, we must have $c\ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need distinct real roots, so necessarily $\Delta=b^2-4ac>0$.  Furthermore, the product of the roots, $\frac ca$ must be negative. As the sign of $\frac ca$ is the same as the sign of $ac$, we have $ac<0$.

We may note  that $ac<0$ implies $\Delta>0$, so the first condition is redundant, and finally, the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has a positive root and a negative root if and only if $ac<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Viete equalitites: the sum of the roots is $\;-\cfrac ba\;$ and their product is $\;\cfrac ca\;$ .

Comment: I know but how can i find the sign of a,b,c to satisfy the given condition

Comment: Hint:  You want the product of roots, which is $\dfrac c a$, to be negative

Comment: Or $\;a>0,\,c<0\;$ or the other way around, the sign of $\;-\frac ba\;$ depends on what root's absolute value is higher...

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be positive.  Then by Vieta $c$ must be negative; here the sign of $b$ doesn't matter.  If conversely $c$ is negative in that case we know that there must be two different solution one of different signs; again the sign of $b$ doesn't matter. Similarly if $a$ is negative.  Hence $ac$ must be negative and the sign of $b$ doesn't matter.

Comment: What is vieta inequality nd how c must be negative

Comment: See DonAntonios answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

We need $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\gt b$.  This happens iff $b^2-4ac\gt b^2$.  Which happens whenever $ac\lt0$.  So $a$ and $c$ must have opposite signs.

Comment: Discriminant become greater than b